# Can't keep background fixed

Tags: html, css, background

When I zoom in a lot, some of my divs expand to the point that they push the page down and create a scroll bar ( the page normally fits on one screen). This is fine, I understand this part. But I want my background to expand with it and be fixed to the back of the page. Instead, the background will only stay where it originally was, and the new space is simply white.

I know how this is supposed to be fixed, but I can't get it to work.
Here's what I have. I'd appreciate any edits or advice.

```
#container{
margin:0;
border:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
padding:0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-bottom:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:auto;
position:static;
background: url("picture.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;}
```

If I need to provide any more information, just let me know.

Comment: Relevant HTML please

Comment: <div id="container">
</div>

The html isn't the problem

Comment: I can't replicate your issue with just the code provided. If you could provide a working snippet or fiddle that can demonstrate your issue, it would be more helpful.